# getArguments return null when passing data between fragments

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-bundle

I have 2 fragments called MedListFragment and MedDetailFragment. In MedListFragment there is a listview with items of Medicine object. When an item is clicked, MedDetailFragment will open with Medicine object passed from MedListFragment.This is the on item click listener in MedListFragment.

**MedListFragment**

```
medlist = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.medlist);

medlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Medicine med = (Medicine) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("medicine", med);

        MedDetailFragment medDetailFragment = new MedDetailFragment();
        medDetailFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MedDetailFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
});
```

Then in MedDetailFragment, I get the bundle like this:

```
public class MedDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_med_detail, container, false);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        Medicine medicine = bundle.getParcelable("medicine");

        return root;
    }
}
```

But it returns error on line `Medicine medicine = bundle.getParcelable("medicine");` saying:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Parcelable android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Why are the arguments turn null? How exactly to get the bundle? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please put log `med`

Comment: you should pass the medDetailFragment object instead the   new MedDetailFragment() fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, medDetailFragment);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at these lines

```
MedDetailFragment medDetailFragment = new MedDetailFragment();
medDetailFragment.setArguments(bundle);

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MedDetailFragment());
```

You are creating two different object of MedDetailFragment. And not passing the object in which you have added the bundle.

Change this Line

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,medDetailFragment );
```

Answer (score 0):

you are passing the new object that's why you getting he null

replace the following line

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MedDetailFragment());
```

with

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, medDetailFragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the lines

```
MedDetailFragment medDetailFragment = new MedDetailFragment();
medDetailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

You instantiated a `MedDetailFragment` fragment, and added your arguments.
Thus far all prerequisites were done and `medDetailFragment` is ready for use.
Now it's time to add it to the placeholder say `fragment_container`.
But in the line

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new `MedDetailFragment`())
```

you created a new instance of the fragment once again with the statement `new` using default constructor that creates a pure instance of `MedDetailFragment` fragment with no additional data (`bundle` object).
Obviously calling `getArguments()` on this instance of the fragment tries to invoke a non-existing part of the fragment causing it to produce `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

**Solution:**

In `MedListFragment` class you have to replece the extra `new MedDetailFragment()` statement in line

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MedDetailFragment());
```

with `medDetailFragment` you'd created previously.

**Optimization:**

It's highly recommended to use factory method approach in case of dealing with `Fragments`. To do so, class `MedDetailFragment` should look like :

```
public class MedDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    public MedDetailFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static MedDetailFragment newInstance(Medicine med) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("medicine", med);
        MedDetailFragment medDetailFragment  = new MedDetailFragment();
        medDetailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return medDetailFragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_med_detail, container, false);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        Medicine medicine = bundle.getParcelable("medicine");

        return root;
    }
}
```

and in class `MedListFragment` you should simply replace the two lines

```
MedDetailFragment medDetailFragment = new MedDetailFragment();
medDetailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

with just a single line of code:

```
MedDetailFragment medDetailFragment = MedDetailFragment.newInstance(med);
```

This approach encapsulates the mechanism within `MedDetailFragment` class, it's much simpler and easy to debug.

I hope it helps.